# Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.title

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

> Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.title.
> at completeValue (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:594:13)
> at executeField (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:489:19)
> at executeFields (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:413:20)
> at completeObjectValue (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:914:10)
> at completeValue (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:635:12)
> at completeValue (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:584:23)
> at D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:486:9
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async graphqlMiddleware (D:\graphql\Graphql-social-media-project\api\node_modules\express-graphql\index.js:125:26)

When trying to update the values for post like that:

```
post.title = PostInput.title;
post.content = PostInput.content;
post.imageUrl = PostInput.imageUrl;
const result = post.save();
```

My `PostInput` looked had [object null prototype] before but I got rid of it by:

```
PostInput = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(PostInput));
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'eeesss',
  content: 'some real content',
  imageUrl: 'images/4423877f-a37f-46ce-b1bf-db3082d2fe36'
}
```

My `graphql` schema look like this:

```
type Post {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String!
    imageUrl: String!
    creator: User!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
}

type User {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    password: String
    status: String!
    posts: [Post!]!
}

type AuthData {
    token: String!
    userId: String!
}

type PostData {
    posts: [Post!]!
    totalPosts: Int!
}

input UserInput {
    email: String!
    name: String!
    password: String!
}

input PostInput {
    title: String!
    content: String!
    imageUrl: String
}

type RootQuery {
    login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthData!
    posts(page: Int): PostData!
    post(postId: String!): Post!
}

type RootMutation {
    createUser(UserInput: UserInput): User!
    createPost(PostInput: PostInput): Post!
    updatePost(id: ID!, PostInput: PostInput): Post!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
}
```

I don't understand why it says `PostInput.title` is `null` when it clearly not.
BTW, the code is completely working the post indeed gets updated but the error is thrown anyway.
I will be glad for any help :)

Comment: btw it heppens when i try to delete the post too when using only Post.findbyidanddelete()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is with the `Post` being returned, not `PostInput` since the message says Cannot return null for non-nullable field `Post.title` not `PostInput.title`.

Ensure you code isn't trying to return a post object with a null title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `postInput` reach the data, something like this:

```js
if (PostInput) {
  post.title = PostInput.title;
  post.content = PostInput.content;
  post.imageUrl = PostInput.imageUrl;
  const result = post.save();
}
```

Comment: it dosent fix it :(